# BigQuery claims mismatch in type between THEN and ELSE when using CASE

Tags: types, case, google-bigquery

When I execute this query, I'm getting a type mismatch error:

```
SELECT 
   date,
   countA,
   countB,
   CASE 
     WHEN countA>0 then countB/countA
     ELSE 0.0
   END as ratioBA,
   CASE 
     WHEN (countB>0 and countA>0)
       THEN SQRT((1/FLOAT(countA))+(1/FLOAT(countB)))
     WHEN (countB>0 and (countA<0 OR countA IS NULL))
       THEN SQRT(1.0+(1/FLOAT(countB)))
     WHEN (countA>0 and (countB<0 OR countB IS NULL))
       THEN SQRT((1/FLOAT(countA))+1.0)
     ELSE NULL
   END as rel_unc_ratioBA
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project:dataset.tablename_], TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
ORDER BY date ASC
```

The problem seems to be the `CASE` statement calculating `rel_unc_ratioBA`.

This is the error:
    `Error: CASE expects THEN and ELSE expressions to have similar types, but got different type double from ELSE expression which is not compatible with type int64.`

`countB` and `countA` are integer counts that can be 0 to about 1000, or could be NULL.

I thought that `SQRT()` is supposed to return type float, so this shouldn't happen.  I have tried putting the `SQRT()` inside a `FLOAT()` to force the types, but this doesn't work.

I also tried replacing

```
ELSE NULL
```

with

```
ELSE 0.0
```

even though that's not what I really want, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: cannot reproduce your issue. you might want to provide some data samples

Comment: Ok, I will try. That's not easy bc it's proprietary data, but this is already useful, tells me it's probably something with the data rather than the query.

Comment: you shouldn't share your real data. but ideally you should try to narrow down your data to just literally few (5-10) rows still reproducing this error. this would be then example to share after obfuscating if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery legacy SQL has less consistent semantics around type coercion than [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) does. For example, you can try executing the following query using legacy SQL:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN y ELSE z END
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x, CAST(2 AS INTEGER) AS y, 3.14 AS z);
```

This gives:

```
CASE expects THEN and ELSE expressions to have similar types, but got different type double from ELSE expression which is not compatible with type int64.
```

If you uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options" in the UI and run the query again after changing the `INTEGER` to `INT64` (another name for the same type), though, you will get a result of `2`:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN y ELSE z END
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x, CAST(2 AS INT64) AS y, 3.14 AS z);
```

For your particular query, you should be able to express it using standard SQL as:

```
SELECT 
 date,
 countA,
 countB,
 CASE 
   WHEN countA > 0 THEN countB / countA
   ELSE 0.0
 END as ratioBA,
 CASE 
   WHEN (countB > 0 AND countA > 0)
     THEN SQRT((1 / countA) + (1 / countB))
   WHEN (countB > 0 AND (countA < 0 OR countA IS NULL))
     THEN SQRT(1 + (1 / countB))
   WHEN (countA > 0 AND (countB<0 OR countB IS NULL))
     THEN SQRT((1 / countA) + 1)
   ELSE NULL
 END as rel_unc_ratioBA
FROM `project.dataset.tablename_`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >= '2015-01-01'
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

For more on the differences between legacy and standard SQL, see the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: i think that example on top of this answer is not compliant with Legacy SQL because of INT64. So it should be just INTEGER. i can be wrong though :o)

Comment: voting up now :o)

Comment: Ah, right. I'm still not sure why it is called `INTEGER` in legacy SQL; )

Comment: In general this worked, except for the `_PARTIONTIME` part.  I replaced that and the preceding line with: `FROM \`project.dataset.tablename_*\`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '2015-01-01'`